# C++ vector not inserting

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following

```
std::vector<Cube> well = vector<Cube>();
createCube(well, x, y, z, id);
```

Later I try to insert a Cube into the vector like this,

```
void Viewer::createCube(std::vector<Cube> vec, int x, int y, int z, int id) {
    float rgb[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    vec.push_back(Cube(QMatrix4x4(), -1));
    int loc = vec.size() - 1;
    std::cout << "loc:" << loc << std::endl;
    vec.at(vec.size() - 1).matrix.translate(x,y,z);
}
```

I get output loc = 0.

Why is it not the new Cube to my Vector?

Comment: You can use `vec.back()` instead of `vec.at(vec.size() - 1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing the vector by value to the createCube function; that means that your vector is copied and then the element is added to the new vector and not to the original one. You can fix it by changing your method signature to:

```
void Viewer::createCube(std::vector<Cube>& vec, int x, int y, int z, int id)
```

Comment: But the temporary copy of `vec` could be `push_back`ed to insert a `Cube`. And as the `vec.size()` is inside the function only, shouldn't it show `vec.size()` as 1?

Comment: @ShauryaChats: It *is* showing `vec.size()` as 1. You're initializing `loc` with `vec.size()-1` and it's showing as 0, indicating that `vec.size()` was 1.